# C# RadGridView SortOrder ascending on ImageColumn - image sorting behaviour

Tags: c#, sorting, telerik, radgridview

I'm using `Telerik RadGridView` to show some stuff which I should be able to sort. I created a short test example with one image column. If the user clicks on the header cell it automatically sorts ascending and descending. Well thats what I think I need. I filled the `RadGridView` with three images and I named these images "a.png", "b.png" and "c.png" ("a.png" is a red bullet, "b.png" is a yellow bullet and "c.png" is a green bullet). If I sort ascending it should be like:

- red ("a.png")
- yellow ("b.png")
- green ("c.png")

But it is the following:

- red ("a.png")
- green ("c.png")
- yellow ("b.png")

That makes no sense to me. You can see my code in which I'm adding the bullets here:

```
foreach (string item in list)
{
    if (item.Length < 5)
    {
        bullet = Properties.Resources.a; // red
    }

    else if (item.Length > 5)
    {
        bullet = Properties.Resources.b; // yellow
    }

    else if (item.Length == 5)
    {
        bullet = Properties.Resources.c; // green
    }

    radGridView1.Rows.Add(bullet);
}

radGridView1.Columns["imgCol"].SortOrder = RadSortOrder.Ascending;
```

So my question is:

Depending on **what** is the `RadGridView` sorting the images? I thought it is the image name but as you can see it isn't. Or is the way I'm adding the bullets causing any problems with the sort behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In order to control your sorting, use a [Sort Descriptor](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-sorting-setting-sorting-programmatically.html)

```
this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.EnableSorting = true;

SortDescriptor descriptor = new SortDescriptor();
descriptor.PropertyName = "bullet column name";
descriptor.Direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
this.radGridView1.MasterTemplate.SortDescriptors.Add(descriptor);
```

Place this in the `Sort Command` in order to set ascending and descending

Comment: Thanks, but using the `SortDescriptor` class doesn't sort them correct as well. It has the same effect as the code I used before. What do you mean by "Sort Command"? You mean an event? There isn't an event called "Sort" or something like this, or I just can't find it.

Comment: @Tyler are you putting the descriptor on the column, or on the `mastertemplate`?

Comment: I do exactly the same as you. So on `MasterTemplate`